# How to eliminate no-neighbour data when doing spatial clustering

Tags: r, list, cluster-computing, spatial

Hello wonderful people!

I'm trying to run a cluster analysis on some data that I've mapped on a choropleth map. It's the `% participation rates per constituency`.

I'm trying to run a `Moran_result` test, but am unable to get the data in list format. I keep getting the error: `"Error in nb2listw(nb) : Empty neighbour sets found"`.

I assume this is because some constituencies (like the Isle of White) have no neighbours. I can't find online what constituencies are islands or have no neighbours, and wondered if there is a speedier way to by-pass solve this issue in R, rather than googling all 573 England and Wales constituencies.

Can you help?

Ideas: I thought that maybe I could create "fake" polygons to surround all constituencies with no value so at the very least they could be listed. Or maybe there is a way of searching which have no neighbours and then removing them? Both of these I'm unsure how to do.

[image: data]

My goal: I wan't to get a few spatial clusters where the participation rates are similar and then extract that data so I can compare it to a regression model I have. If you know of another way to do this, other than above, please let me know.

I've tried: `new_dataframe <- filter(election_merged_sf, !is.na(nb)`, but this doesn't actually remove any objects. I assume this is because it is testing whether there are numeric neighbours, when it needs to be done spatially.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: As @MrFlick pointed out, your question needs to be reproducible. In addition to the data and code, don't forget to include the libraries you're using. There are many duplicate function names out there.